# Properties of a cell in Excel (used in VBScript)?

Tags: excel, vbscript

What properties/attributes does a cell have in Excel? I searched online but the best thing I could find was [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567%28v=office.15%29.aspx). However, this doesn't include a list attributes of a cell like `.Font`, `.Value`, etc.

I'm trying to find a way to get the hyperlink located in a cell in VBScript. The value of the cell is different from the link. I tried `Cells(1, 1).Range("A1").Hyperlinks(1).Address` and just `Cells(1,1).Hyperlink`, but neither are working.

Also, is there any detailed documentation for Excel use in VBScript? I've used the MSDN and W3Schools documentation, but neither of them have any Excel-specific information. I've found that in many places, Excel use in VBA or VB is different from in VBScript.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know of documentation specific to VBScript (I've only worked with VBA in Excel). But if my post answered your question or was useful, feel free to accept it or give it an upvote! :)

Comment: I've added additional information regarding your hyperlink issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194567%28v=office.15%29.aspx), `Cells` is a `Range` object. You can either refer to a specific cell (item) or a range of cells, but the individual cell is just a specific instance of a `Range` object.

Therefore, you should refer to the list of [Range properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn301006%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

With regard to getting the hyperlink in a cell. If the hyperlink is in A1, you can use

```
Worksheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Name
```

Here is additional documentation about [Hyperlinks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835563%28v=office.15%29.aspx). The documentation looks sparse, but if you click the arrows for "Hyperlink Object" in the left-hand menu, you'll see all the properties and methods.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see that, but this worked perfectly. Thank you for also including the links to all the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1):

I think part of what you are missing is how to gain access to Excel objects within VBScript.  The way you gain access to Excel objects in VbScript is to call the following in to your script

```
Set myxlObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myxlApplication = myxlObject.Application
```

With that you will be able to do practically anything that you have done in VBA but now in vbScript and then you will need to call that application object to gain access to the other objects.  For example:

```
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( "C:\Wherever\Whatever.xlsx" )
```

For more information about the properties and methods that you can access via this "Excel.Application" object see this page: [Application Object (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

The following script will output the names and addresses of hyperlinks on a worksheet in a particular range to the console.

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set myxlObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myxlApplication = myxlObject.Application
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( curDir & "\24048353.xlsx" ) 'Change to the actual workbook that has the Hyperlinks
Set myWorkSheet = myWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

myxlApplication.Visible = False

Set rng = myWorkSheet.Range("A2:A3") 'Change to the actual range that has the Hyperlinks

For Each row In rng.Rows

    myLinkName = row.Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Name
    myLinkURL = row.Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address

    wscript.echo myLinkName & " " & myLinkURL

Next
```

Run this using [cscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201405/what-is-the-equivalent-of-a-batch-echo-command-using-vbscript)

Possibly a more practical use of this script is to output the results to a file as such:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
curDir = fso.GetAbsolutePathName(".")

Set myLinksFile = fso.OpenTextFile( curDir & "\mylinks.txt", 8, True)

Set myxlObject = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myxlApplication = myxlObject.Application
Set myWorkBook = myxlApplication.Workbooks.Open( curDir & "\24048353.xlsx" ) 'Change to the actual workbook that has the Hyperlinks
Set myWorkSheet = myWorkBook.Worksheets(1)

myxlApplication.Visible = False

Set rng = myWorkSheet.Range("A2:A3") 'Change to the actual range that has the Hyperlinks

For Each row In rng.Rows

    myLinkName = row.Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Name
    myLinkURL = row.Cells(1, 1).Hyperlinks(1).Address

    mylinksFile.WriteLine myLinkName & ", " & myLinkURL

Next

mylinksFile.Close
```